# TypeError: this.decodeHtml is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just migrated to VueJS 2, and now, I have an issue.

In a filter, I call a custom function, but I get: `TypeError: this.decodeHtml is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
 new Vue({
         el: '#modal',
         data: {...}
         computed: {...}
         methods: {
                decodeHtml: function decodeHtml(html) {
                        var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
                        txt.innerHTML = html;
                        return txt.value;
                    },
         ... },
        filters: {
                    html: function html(_html) {
                        return this.decodeHtml(_html);
                    }
                }
```

in my HTML, I call it :  `@{{ categoryFullName | html }}`

Any idea why??? Before migration it was working fine.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/t07z08zt/14/)

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(this)`? And why are you naming the function after the keyword `function`?

Comment: how should I do to name it???

Comment: in your case: `decodeHtml: function() {...}`. But i can be wrong and that can also be a valid way to name functions.

Comment: it gives me a Window object. I added invocation in my question

Comment: Just for the heck of it (this is obviously a scope problem), switch to arrow functions to define the functions (both of them). See if that does anything. so, "decodeHTML: ( html ) => { .... return etc. }, and html: ( _html ) => { return etc. }

Comment: what do you mean by arrow function???

Comment: ES6 arrow functions. They resolve scope differently.

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I write it? I'm not so good in JS :(

Comment: This is what he's suggesting `decodeHtml: (html) => {}` and `html: (_html) => {}`

Comment: I wrote it like that, first option didn't work: ```html: (_html) => {
                            return this.decodeHtml(_html);
                        }``` still have the same issue

Comment: Your `console.log(this)` should return a Vue object and not a Windows object.

Comment: I changed : new Vue({... to let vm = new Vue({... and use vm.decodeHtml, but vm returns null. But in Vue Debugging in chrome, I can see all my objects

Comment: Can you create and share a https://jsfiddle.net/ to help us understand whats wrong? Try to recreate it as close as you want it in your project.

Comment: @Jackowski https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/t07z08zt/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with scope. On your `html` function the `this` variable is a `Window` object and not a `Vue` object as it should be.

The workaround you can do is instead of calling the `decodeHtml` function you implement it in your filter. Like this:

```
filters: {
  html: (html) => {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
  }
}
```